# Insert a word into a 2d array

Tags: c

Hello I want to create a 2D array of full stops and insert the word hello into it could anyone show me how to do this?
This is my effort so far.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

char * generate_2D_array( )
{
    char a[5] = "hello";
    char grid[12][12];
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0;i < 12; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 12; j++)
        {
                grid[i][j] = ".";
        }
    }

    for (i = 0;i < 5; i++)
    {
            grid[i][j] = a[i];
    }       
}




int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  generate_2D_array( );
  system("PAUSE");  
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code has a lot of errors:

1. Your `generate_2D_array()` function is declared to return `char *` but it does not return anything.
2. You declare a local variable in `generate_2D_array()` and apparently you want to return that, you should't.
3. You assign a string literal `const char *` to a `char`, namely

   ```
   grid[i][j] = ".";
   ```

   you need to assign the character constant `'.'` instead.

Your code would work with little changes, take a look

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void
generate_2D_array(char array[12][13], const char *hello)
{
    int  i, j;
    for (i = 0 ; i < 12 ; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0 ; j < 12 ; j++)
        {
            array[i][j] = '.';
        }
        array[i][j] = '\0';
    }

    for (i = 0 ; (hello[i] != '\0') && (i < 12) ; i++)
    {
        array[0][i] = hello[i];
        /*    ^  ^ here you can't use `j' because it's out of bounds */
        /*    |    so put it on the first row? --------+             */
        /*    |                                        |             */
        /*    +----------------------------------------+             */
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char array[12][13];
    int  i;

    generate_2D_array(array, "hello");
    for (i = 0 ; i < 12 ; ++i)
        printf("%s\n", array[i]);
    return 0;
}
```